# Libgdx bouncy effect in a wall

Tags: android, libgdx, physics

I have an element inside the screen and I want to set my phone's bounds as a wall where elements are bouncing. I want it to be physically correct. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know the screen bounds:

```
int screenHeight = getScreenHeight();
int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
```

Then, you have to initialize the velocity vector for your bouncing square. In this example it'll be <1,1>:

```
BouncingSquare bouncingSquare = new BouncingSquare();
bouncingSquare.velocity.x = 1;
bouncingSquare.velocity.y = 1;
```

Also, for simplicity, I recommend you to have a method in the BouncingSquare class that helps you to compute the left, top, right and bottom coordinates of your square:

```
int getLeft()
{
   return this.position.x;
}

int getTop()
{
   return this.position.y;
}

int getRight()
{
   return this.position.x + this.size.width;
}

int getBottom()
{
   return this.position.y + this.size.height;
}
```

In your update method, you have to check if the square is out of the screen bounds and invert the velocity values if necessary:

```
if (bouncingSquare.getLeft() <= 0 || bouncingSquare.getRight() >= screenWidth)
     bouncingSquare.velocity.x *= -1;   

if (bouncingSquare.getTop() <= 0 || bouncingSquare.getBottom() >= screenHeight)
     bouncingSquare.velocity.y *= -1;
```

Finally, just update the position:

```
bouncingSquare.position.x += bouncingSquare.velocity.x;
bouncingSquare.position.y += bouncingSquare.velocity.y;
```